# ReactJS: Handle multiple checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I am working on multiple checkboxes on my site. This is the my state

```
 state = {
    data: {
      airport_transport: false,
      night_club: false,
      wifi: false,
      parking: false,
      swimming_pool: false,
      restaurant: false,
      gym: false,
      air_conditioner: false,
      laundry_services: false,
      bar_lounge: false,
      disabled_services: false,
      elevator: false,
      shuttle_bus_service: false,
      cards_accepted: false,
    },
    errors: {},
  };
```

This is how i am handling the state of the checkboxes. I am posting only few handle methods

```
 toggleChangeShuttle = () => {
    let data = this.state.data;
    data.shuttle_bus_service = !data.shuttle_bus_service;
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  toggleChangeAirport = () => {
    let data = this.state.data;
    data.airport_transport = !data.airport_transport;
    this.setState({ data });
  };
  toggleChangeCooling = () => {
    let data = this.state.data;
    data.air_conditioner = !data.air_conditioner;
    this.setState({ data });
  };
  toggleChangeNightClub = () => {
    let data = this.state.data;
    data.night_club = !data.night_club;
    this.setState({ data });
  };
```

And finally this is how i am rendering. I am omitting extra render methods

```
<div className="form-check">
                <label className="container">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={this.state.data.air_conditioner}
                    onChange={this.toggleChangeCooling}
                    className="form-check-input"
                  />
                  <span className="checkmark"></span>
                  Air Conditioner
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="form-check">
                <label className="container">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={this.state.data.airport_transport}
                    onChange={this.toggleChangeAirport}
                    className="form-check-input"
                  />
                  <span className="checkmark"></span>
                  Airport Transport
                </label>{" "}
              </div>
              <div className="form-check">
                <label className="container">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={this.state.data.bar_lounge}
                    onChange={this.toggleChangeBarLounge}
                    className="form-check-input"
                  />
                  <span className="checkmark"></span>
                  Bar Lounge
                </label>{" "}
              </div>
```

Now this looks manual with lots of repetitions. Is there a compact clean way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your checkboxes (*as your state properties*) and use a single method that uses the name of the checkbox to set the state

```js
toggleCheckbox = (e) => {
  const checkboxName = e.target.name;
  this.setState((state) => ({
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      [checkboxName]: !state.data[checkboxName]
    }
  }));
};


<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  name="airport_transport"
  checked={this.state.data.airport_transport} 
  onChange={this.toggleCheckbox} 
  className="form-check-input" 
/>
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply but i chose this solution over the other one as it has more information. Thank you for your assistance sir

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a much easier way to do this. Instead of doing a separate function for each property, do something along these lines:

```
onChange = (event) => {
    let name = event.target.name
    this.setState(prevState => (
        {
         data[name]: !prevState.data[property]
        }
    )
}
```

You can set the "name" prop on each input to equal the piece of state that you want to change. This will pass the event to the function, and you can dynamically set the state according to which textbox was checked.